# Multi Resource Files for same languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, internationalization

I have a MVC application that works as two different products in the same web project, I also have multi language resource files. But from now on, these two products will have some different strings/words, even tho they software still working similarly.

*My resources files today are;*

> "resource.en.resx"
>
> "resource.es.resx"
>
> "resource.pt.resx"

I didn't find any good example of how to have two different resource files, according to with the user type, or company type + multi language file.

*The perfect Scenario*

> "resource.academic.en.resx"
>
> "resource.business.en.resx"
>
> "resource.academic.es.resx"
>
> "resource.business.es.resx"
>
> "resource.academic.pt.resx"
>
> "resource.business.pt.resx"

Any ideas how to do it?